# managing complex JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a complex input JSON, something like this:

```
@json = {"project":"bla",
    "analysis": {"id":"123","title":"Test"}, 
    "data":{"axis": {"name":"column", "label":"demo","values": ["one", "two"]},
           "series": [{"label":"text", "values":["1", "2", "3"]}, 
                    {"label":"text2", "values":["4", "5", "6"]}
]}}
```

(more complex and length that this example)

two question:

1. it exists a RoR method that can delete on the fly something in the json? something like
   `@json.destroy['analysis']` that eliminate only the "analysis" key-value couple?
2. how can i navigate (for example) in the values of the series? I can do if the json is simple with a `do each`, but here must I do a concecation of `do each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the JSON to a hash, remove the key, and then convert back to JSON:

```
require "json"
hash = JSON.parse(@json)
hash.delete("analysis")
@json = hash.to_json
```

Comment: thank you, good idea. and to navigate in the JSON you have any solutions? maybe using the hash too? but how can i do in this multidimensional json?

Comment: The entire structure of the JSON will be turned into Ruby objects. Anything surrounded by curly braces will become a hash. Anything surrounded by square brackets will become an array. Navigate those structures as you normally would (hash.each, hash[b][c], etc).